# Backbone html select value

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js

I have a form that is bound to a model: user form, which is represented by Backbone.View.extend which has:

```
model:user
```

inside the view:

```
events: {
   'click #payment' : 'updatePayment'
}
```

where payment is a html select with :

```
<div class="span2" id="payment">
    <select class="span12">
         <option value="paypal">paypal</option>
         <option value="check">check</option>
    </select>
</div>

updatePayment: function() {
    var payment = this.$("#payment");
    console.log(payment);
}
```

Sadly payment has no value.
Can someone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Which DOM element is your View using?

Comment: Why use `this.$()` instead of just `$()`?

Comment: @mhu: I'd call using `this.$()` instead of `$()` a standard practice with Backbone, using just `$()` is a bit of a red flag.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/19203230/759452

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a bit hard to tell... but it seems like you want this:

```
events: {
   'change .span12' : 'updatePayment' // listen for change of <select> element.
},

updatePayment: function(event) {
    var payment = event.target.value;
    console.log(payment); // print 'paypal' or 'check'.
}
```