# Backbone.js Change Text based on selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, html-select

I am trying to get some text to change when the user selects a different option in a dropdown box. I am using Backbone.js and am trying to figure out how to get the text belonging to the track when the user chooses an option.

As a follow-up, if I didn't set the value of the option to track.text, but rather track.title, how would I be able to get it from the .js file? I had originally set track.title and track.text in a JSON file. I am trying to learn how to get information from the JSON files. Thanks!!

```
window.LibraryLessonView = LessonView.extend({
events: {
    "change .sel " : "changeText"
},

changeText: function() {
//not sure what I should write here...
}


});
```

This is in my HTML file:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="lesson-template">
         <span class="lesson-title"><%= title %></span>
         <select class="sel">

//get the tracks from the JSON file and put them all in the dropdown
            <% _.each(tracks, function(track) { %>
              <option value = <%= track.title %> ><%= track.title %></option>


          <% }); %>        
          </select>

<p> Blah </P> //I want to change the text here

        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDITED]
that should work for you:

```
changeText: function(e) {
    alert(e.target.value); 
}
```

`e.target` refers to DOM element that triggers change event here. `e.target.value` returns value of currently selected item in select box

Comment: That is resulting in an undefined value being returned to me for some reason - probably because of what mu said.

Comment: yes, my apologize. it was a while since I was working with Backbone. Now I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Thats awesome. As a follow-up, if I didn't set the value of the option to track.text, how would I be able to get it from the .js file? I had originally set track.title and track.text in a JSON file.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Can you elaborate on that? PS. if my answer is correct please mark it as correct :)

Comment: Well, I originally set the value of option to the text field of track (track.text). If I didn't do that, I was wondering how I would be able to get track.text and change the value of Blah in the <p> tag to track.text, which is located in the JSON file

Comment: once you provide your template with values from injected object it will use them and immediately forget about the object after that, so if you won't put somewhere that track.text value in template you won't be able to retrieve it back from the template. I suggest to put that values in data attributes eg. <option value="<%= track.title %>" data-text="<%= track.text %>" > and then you can simply get it in  changeText method with e.target.getAttribute('data-text')

Comment: For some reasons e.target.getAttribute('data-text') returns null. I checked the HTML and the data-text does produce a result, but when I try to do anything with it in the JS, I receive a null.